# Remove drop shadow after hover

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I need to highlight the state when mouse hovers over by adding stroke around the state and adding a drop shadow. But when hover is off, the border stroke is gone, but the drop shadow stays. Is there anyway to remove the drop shadow?

Drop shadow is implemented as a filter. Is it possible to remove a filter at all?

Sample code is here: https://codepen.io/lima01/pen/OJmqgXv

```
var hoverState = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");
hoverState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#ff0000");
hoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 5;

var hoverShadow = hoverState.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter);
hoverShadow.dx = 6;
hoverShadow.dy = 6;
hoverShadow.opacity = 0.3;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default filter for the polygon's default state so that it knows what to revert itself to when the hover state is no longer active. You can do this by setting a DropShadowFilter for the polygon's defaultState to with a zero opacity:

```
var defaultFilter = polygonTemplate.defaultState.filters.push(
  new am4core.DropShadowFilter()
);
defaultFilter.opacity = 0;
```